# \markboth inside tikz \node text not working

Tags: tikz-pgf, header-footer

If `\markboth` is used inside a tikz node text, this `\markboth` does nothing.

- Output of pdflatex, xelatex, and lualatex are the same.
- Does this work as expect?
- I noticed that an inside-group `\markboth`, like `{\markboth{lefthead}{righthead}}`, still works. Then what does tikz do that "blocks" `\markboth`?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\tikz\node[red] {\markboth{tikz left}{tikz right}};
contents \newpage contents
\end{document}
```

---

Where does this question raise from:

- The standard document class uses something like `\chapter*{...\martboth{...}{...}}` inside `\tableofcontents` to generate the title of toc and change the marker.
- In some fancy section heading styles, the argument of `\chapter[*]{arg}` is passed to a `tikz` drawing.
- So with these section styles, `\tableofcontents` fails to change marker.

I know how to make a workaround, but I am curious about how and why it fails.

Comment: Sorry for the question, but why you need to use `\markboth` inside a TikZ node?

Comment: @CarLaTeX I have added to the question.

Comment: It won't work, \mark commands can't excape boxes - try e.g. with a simple \mbox{\markboth{left}{right}}. Move the \markboth command outside the tikz code.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every `tikzpicture` is in a box, and as @UlrikeFischer commented,

> `\mark` commands can't escape boxes

This is discussed in *The TeXbook*, chapter 23 on page 259, the first paragraph.